# gallery images move out of frame on touch

Tags: android

i have prepared a custom gallery view, it loades images from anywhere on the disk and slides them in Drawable(). but the problem is as you see in picture , when i click one an image ,it moves out of its frame.

this happened after i turned source from Integer[] pic = {R.drawable.....}
to to an Integer array in the vector, and changed imagesource(arg[0]) to

```
iv.setImageDrawable(mySDCardImages.get(arg0).getDrawable());



LinearLayout imageView;
Integer [] mThumbIds;
Vector<ImageView> mySDCardImages;


  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_image_explore);
    final Vector<ImageView> mySDCardImages;
    mySDCardImages = new Vector<ImageView>();

    List<Integer> drawablesId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int picIndex=12345;
    File sdDir = new File("/sdcard/Pictures");
    File[] sdDirFiles = sdDir.listFiles();
    for(File singleFile : sdDirFiles)
    {
       ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(this);

 myImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(singleFile.getAbsolutePath()));
       myImageView.setId(picIndex);
       picIndex++;
       drawablesId.add(myImageView.getId());
       mySDCardImages.add(myImageView);
    }
    Integer [] mThumbIds = (Integer[])drawablesId.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    this.mThumbIds = mThumbIds;
    this.mySDCardImages=mySDCardImages;
    try {
        // InputStream in = (new URL("www.google.com").openStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    Gallery ga = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
    ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    imageView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    "You have selected picture " + (arg2 + 1)
                            + " of Antartica", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
            imageView.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
            TouchImageView touchImageView = new TouchImageView(
                    GalleryView.this);

 touchImageView.setImageDrawable(mySDCardImages.get(arg2).getDrawable());;
            LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

 imageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            touchImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            imageView.addView(touchImageView);
        }

    });

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    int imageBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(

 R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        ta.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
        iv.setImageDrawable(mySDCardImages.get(arg0).getDrawable());
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
        iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
        return iv;
    }
}
```

and here is my touchimage adapter just in case:

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

private static final String TAG = "Touch";
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

 // We can be in one of these 3 states
 static final int NONE = 0;
 static final int DRAG = 1;
 static final int ZOOM = 2;
 int mode = NONE;

 // Remember some things for zooming
 PointF start = new PointF();
 PointF mid = new PointF();
 float oldDist = 1f;

 Context context;

 public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;

    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
            WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(rawEvent);

            // Dump touch event to log
//                if (Viewer.isDebug == true){
//                    dumpEvent(event);
//                }

            // Handle touch events here...
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(event.getX() - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(event.getY() - start.y);
                if (xDiff < 8 && yDiff < 8){
                    performClick();
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    // ...
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() -    
 start.y);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
 }


 public void setImage(Bitmap bm, int displayWidth, int displayHeight) { 
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);

    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    if ((displayHeight / bm.getHeight()) >= (displayWidth / bm.getWidth())){
        scale =  (float)displayWidth / (float)bm.getWidth();
    } else {
        scale = (float)displayHeight / (float)bm.getHeight();
    }

    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);


    // Center the image
    float redundantYSpace = (float)displayHeight - (scale * (float)bm.getHeight()) ;
    float redundantXSpace = (float)displayWidth - (scale * (float)bm.getWidth());

    redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float)2;


    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}


/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void dumpEvent(WrapMotionEvent event) {
    // ...
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
        "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(
                action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
        sb.append(";");
    }
    sb.append("]");
    Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
}

/** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
private float spacing(WrapMotionEvent event) {
    // ...
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, WrapMotionEvent event) {
    // ...
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}



}
```

sorry for its too long being, have you guys experienced this before? do you guys know where could the problem be from? wish could post the image

In addition, Images are not fitting to the screen. no longer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to be very frank.  You are doing a lot of things incorrectly and your problem could be from a slew of things. Its also very hard to read your code when you do things like: naming a variable `imageView` which is actually a `LinearLayout` that uses an `R.id.ImageView01` id tag.  My suggestion as follows:

1. Fix your variable naming so we can understand your code
2. Ditch your `TouchImageView` and use [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView). It's solid, bug free, works great, and provides all the functionality you'd expect of an `ImageView` for an image gallery. I've personally used it in production code with no issues.
3. Your entire `ImageAdapter` is implemented incorrectly. Just toss it out.  Instead extend an `ArrayAdapter<Drawable>`.  Construct it by passing in your `mySDCardImages` and override the `getView()` method to inflate your views.
4. You really need to learn about the ViewHolder paradigm and how to properly code the adapter's `getView()` method. Here's a quick [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) I found. Even though it talks about `ListViews` the same concept applies with `Gallery`.
5. `mySDCardImages` should **not** be storing `ImageViews`.  Just have it store the `Drawable` directly.
6. I'm not sure what `mThumbIds` is for...but from what I can see, just delete it. Doesn't seem to serve any purpose.
7. Don't be afraid of creating views in XML. Unless you have specific reasons, you should always try to keep all the layouts and views in XML.
8. Is there a specific reason you need the `Vector` class? Unless you really need the `synchronization`, it's better to stick with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: tnx alot, it is actually, and by the way, 1 month ago i didnt know what even an activity is , and now im here thanks to people like you :) sorry about that